# How to Handle Form Submission From Redirecting When Any Validation Error Occur

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dojo, spring-webflow

How to Handle Form Submission From Redirecting When Any Validation Error Occur
I have Created form inside overlay which contains fields how do I show error back on the overlay . because after submiting the form if any error occur it returns the register page ,so How do I show Overlay open
    Here is the Code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void registerForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("registerInfo", new UserRegistrationForm());
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/reg", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String create(
        @Valid @ModelAttribute("registerInfo") UserRegistrationForm userRegistrationForm,
        BindingResult result) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "register";
    }
    userService.addUser(userRegistrationForm);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Comment: Please show some code to understand what you did exactly.

Comment: you have to post your code in original question by clicking `edit` , not as a comment. Please delete this comment.